# Polymer 1.0 Custom Element Using paper-dialog- better way to do this?

Tags: polymer

I have a custom element `video-player` which uses `paper-dialog`.

They way it is now, seems kind of hacky. I have a external button(it has to be a external button for my design) that opens it with:

```
bob = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('video-player');
bob.querySelector('paper-dialog').open()
```

---

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-youtube/google-youtube.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="video-player">
  <template>
    <paper-dialog>
      <div class="layout horizontal">
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss>
          <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
        </paper-button>
      </div>
      <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
        <google-youtube style="height: 100%;"
          video-id="YMWd7QnXY8E"
          rel="1"
          start="5"
          playsinline="0"
          controls="2"
          showinfo="0"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          autoplay="1">
        </google-youtube>
      </div>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "video-player"
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

</paper-dialog>
```

I can not inherit the `paper-dialog` behavior(which would be `iron-overlay` because it won't relate to that specific `paper-dialog` element.

Since this seems kind of hacky, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Please read as follows:

1.The last deleted

```
</paper-dialog>
```

2.paper-button component add

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

Sources are as follows:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-youtube/google-youtube.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="video-player">
  <template>
    <paper-dialog>
      <div class="layout horizontal">
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss>
          <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
        </paper-button>
      </div>
      <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
        <google-youtube style="height: 100%;"
          video-id="YMWd7QnXY8E"
          rel="1"
          start="5"
          playsinline="0"
          controls="2"
          showinfo="0"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          autoplay="1">
        </google-youtube>
      </div>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "video-player"
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```